# I never say 2 arrays equal to each other but in output they do in C

Tags: c, arrays

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void sort(int array[], int n)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < (n - i - 1); j++)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j + 1])
            {
                    temp = array[j];
                    array[j] = array[j + 1];
                    array[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
}

int main()
{
    int n, lower, upper, numbers[500], m = 0, sub_numbers[m], k = 0, index[k];
    int i;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &lower, &upper);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((numbers[i] > lower) && (numbers[i] < upper))
        {
            sub_numbers[m] = numbers[i];
            index[k] = i;
            m++;
            k++;
        }
    }
    sort(sub_numbers, m);
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
        printf("%d ", index[i]);


    return 0;
}
```

I never say that sub_numbers[m] = index[k] but in the output I get index[k] on both lines while I have to have sub_numbers on the first and indexes on the second. if I comment //index[k] = i; then both arrays are sub_numbers arrays

Answer (score 6):

You have:

```
int n, lower, upper, numbers[500], m = 0, sub_numbers[m], k = 0, index[k];
```

You have UB (undefined behaviour) — `sub_numbers` is a variable-length array (VLA) of size 0, and so is `index`.  Strict C doesn't allow arrays of size 0 (C11 [§6.7.6 Array declarators ¶1,¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2)).  GCC does allow size zero arrays, but storing anything in them is UB.

With UB, anything is possible — there is no point in speculating on what else is happening.

You could reasonably sensibly fix your code by not defining your arrays until you've read `n` from the user (and validated it for basic sanity — greater than zero, less than, for sake of argument, 65,536).  You'd then write:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);   // Check success
// Check n for sanity
int numbers[n], sub_numbers[n], index[n];
```

You've now got three arrays that should fit on the stack of a normal desktop or server-class machine — if you've got an embedded system, you may need to be more careful.  I've limited the arrays to about 3/4 MiB (each one being 1/4 MiB if the size is 65,536).  If you need to process more data, you won't be reading from a user typing, and you should use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` and friends.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are allocating an array with a variable size without`malloc`-like functions. For example `index[k]` with `k = 0`. It will cause undefined behavior afterward. Now, if you want to allocate the array with `malloc`, you can't put anything inside an array with size zero. Therefore, you can modify your code by using `malloc` (if you desire dynamic size allocation) and higher values for the size of the arrays.